# How to backup & Restore PostgreSQL database in Windows7?

Tags: windows, postgresql, pgadmin

I am new to Postgres database. I have to get the backup from Production Server (pgAdmin Version is 9.2.4) & restore it on my local machine (I have pgAdmin Version 9.4). I tried to get backup by right clicking on database -> Backup to get the .backup file. Like shown in below image:

[image]

But when I try to restore the backup file, I get many errors.

I also want to know whether having different ports at both system can also create issues while restoring backups. As When I tried to restore backup of same system had no problems.

Comment: I personally find using [the command line tools](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/reference-client.html) directly **much** easier than the pgAdmin UI (which I find highly confusing). Btw: there is no "pgAdmin version 9.4". It's **Postgres** that has the version is 9.4

Comment: What kind of errors you get?

Answer (score 49):

**To backup a database** you can use `pg_dump.exe`:

1. Open Powershell
2. Go to Postgres bin folder. For example:

   ```
   cd "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin"
   ```
3. Enter the command to dump your database. For example:

   ```
   ./pg_dump.exe -U postgres -d my_database_name -f D:\Backup\<backup-file-name>.sql
   ```
4. Type password for your postgres user

**To restore a database** you can use `psql.exe`. *(Note, the following is extracted from Alexandr Omelchenko's helpful answer which has been deleted for reasons not clear to me.)*

1. Open Powershell
2. Go to Postgres bin folder. For example:

   ```
   cd "C:\ProgramFiles\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin"
   ```
3. Enter the command to restore your database. For example:

   ```
   ./psql.exe -U postgres -d my_database_name -f D:\Backup\<backup-file-name>.sql
   ```
4. Type password for your postgres user

Comment: you can also provide the password throught the PGPASSWORD variable.  
SET PGPASSWORD=mypassword

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck here when creating the database dump file due to version mismatch.
So I follow the below command to get the backup and restore.

```
pg_dump -h localhost -U postgres -p 5432 YourDbName > BackupFileName.dump
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can try below cmd code. If you trouble with restoring from pgAdmin4, you can try this.
First you should find the path pg_restore.exe. It is generally in

> C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin>

run the below code after changing database name and backup path

```
pg_restore.exe --verbose --clean -U "postgres" --dbname databaseName c:\database.backup
```