# How should i give the file path when i use windows machine in PostgreSQL?

Tags: windows, postgresql, file

How should I give the file path when I use Windows?

this is my command

```
pg_dump -F p -U test -h localhost db_test -f C:\Users\Proobook\Desktop\Newfolder\test.sql
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I  run  this  in my  windows command line  in their i got error   near the  -f C:\Users\Proobook\Desktop\Newfolder\test.sql

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048412/how-to-backup-restore-postgresql-database-in-windows7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048412/how-to-backup-restore-postgresql-database-in-windows7)